# Sticky Column and Row Names in Rhandsontable

Tags: javascript, css, r, handsontable, rhandsontable

I am currently developing a Shiny application and utilizing the `rhandsontable` package to display a table. Here is the code snippet I am working with:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    df <- data.frame(matrix(1:(50**2), ncol = 50))
    rhandsontable(df, height = 10000, width = 10000)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My goal is to implement sticky column and row names in the `rhandsontable` output. However, I want to achieve this without constraining the height or width of the table. I've currently set a large `height` and `width` to avoid multiple scrollbars (from the constrained table and the large webpage), as it can be confusing for users when these scrollbars are in close proximity. Note also that in my project, the data from the table is dynamically generated, so I don't know in advance what is the exact height and width of the table.

I've attempted several methods to achieve this, but none have been successful.

---

**Edit**
I would like my `rhandsontable` to exhibit the same behavior in terms of sticky row names and row headers (without limiting the height or width of the table) as this `handsontable` in JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example1" class="hot"></div>

    <script>
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            data[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
                data[i][j] = null;
            }
        }

        var container = document.getElementById('example1');
        var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            filters: false,
            dropdownMenu: false
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the sticky/frozen rows and columns are triggered by scroll bar events (which is what I assume you mean by using a box).  The documentation for the package says "scroll through the table to see the fixed row and column" `https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#Fixed`.  There might be a custom JS/CSS approach to tie the events to something other than the scrollbar, or you could make the scrollbars of the box invisible, but I'm not seeing any obvious approach in `rhandsontable` to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "the box"?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I mean I want the whole table to be displayed without the x- o y-scrolls.

Comment: The `rhandsontable` package offers a lot of possibility, but the height and width problems are very frustrating.  Often you get dueling scroll bars between the table widget and the webpage.  In your HTML, the table captures my mouse's attempts at scrolling the table, so my browser won't scroll the page.  It is precisely this kind of problem that led me write R code to prepare a raw HTML table and then I fudged some Shiny+JS code to get the functionality I needed.  If you like the JavaScript Handsontable package, just insert it directly into your Shiny app and write your own input handler.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the hot_table function within the rhandsontable call to make row names sticky (stickyRows = TRUE) and include column headers (colHeaders = TRUE)

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    df <- data.frame(matrix(1:(50**2), ncol = 50))
    
    rhandsontable(df, height = 500, width = 800) %>%
    #rhandsontable(df) %>% #or use this
      hot_table(stickyRows = TRUE, 
                colHeaders = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @Umar, unfortunately your solution does not work as the table is being boxed. If you set the `height` and `widht` to a very large number (e.g., 10000) to avoid boxing the table, you'll see that the column header and row names are not sticky anymore.

Answer (score 1):

An approach based on hiding the scrollbars with CSS.  You can change the width and height.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

# Add CSS to hide scrollbars - may not work on all browsers.
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "::-webkit-scrollbar {
         display: none;
        }"
    ))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

# Set the width and height to reasonable values to get the hidden scroll bars working.
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    df <- data.frame(matrix(1:(50**2), ncol = 50))
    rhandsontable(df, width = "100%", height = 500,
                  fixedRowsTop = 0, fixedColsLeft = 0)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a good trick indeed, but the table is still boxed. I'd have to provide the exact width and height for this to work without boxing, which is not optimal given with tables that are generated dynamically or when the table is change by the user (e.g. suppresses a row). Unfortunately, not really the approach I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you might use JavaScript directly

```
     library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
  ),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .rhandsontable .ht_master {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
      }
    "))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({
    df <- data.frame(matrix(1:(50**2), ncol = 50))
    rhandsontable(df, options = list(
      stickyHeaders = TRUE
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This sets the overflow-x property to hidden for the main container to avoid the horizontal scrollbar. Additionally, the stickyHeaders option in rhandsontable ensures sticky row and column headers without additional JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: I gave it a try and it made the header and row column disappear.

Comment: Plz refer editted answer

Comment: Still not working properly. The header is not sticky, and there's a x-scroll bar for the table, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Plz refer latest edited answer  hope it will work

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working...